# Select by attribute using modulo operation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sql, select-by-attribute, where-clause

In ArcMap 10.5, I want to select the rows where the modulus of the objectid by 3 equals 1.

How to write a SQL sentence in select by attribute window?

My current query statement is something like this:

```
MOD( [OBJECTID],3)=1
```

but unfortunately it selects all of the rows. What's the problem with that?

Comment: Which GIS software and version are you using? For something like this, you may need to use the modulus operator: `"id" %3 = 1`

Comment: Please [edit] the question to specify the GIS software in use, the format of the base data, and it's a database table, the RDBMS in which that table resides.

Comment: You still haven't specified the format of the data source.

Answer (score 5):

The following query works:

```
MOD("column_name", 3) = 1
```

where column values are of type **integer** belonging to a shapefile TOC.

Take a look at these related questions:

- [Selecting contours which heights are integers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58224/selecting-contours-which-heights-are-integers/58225#58225)
- [Selecting rows where remainder (modulo) is 1 after division by 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756928/selecting-rows-where-remainder-modulo-is-1-after-division-by-2)

If you are querying a table from SQL Server using ArcGIS, then, the `mod` expression won't work. Use the modulo operator (%), instead. See:

- [Using the MOD expression on an SQL Feature Class is not possible?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213066/using-the-mod-expression-on-an-sql-feature-class-is-not-possible/213067#213067)